# What is jamming my drone?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Occasionally, when I try to deploy my drone near a base I receive a notification that my drone is being jammed.  Is there something nearby I have to disable / destroy to remove the jammer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, there is a Drone Jammer in the base. Usually in the centre of the base.

If you scout the base with your Binoculars it should still highlight for you, as a radar dish and highlight as 'jammer'.

You can blow it up with explosives, or, if they have a generator, disable that will turn it off also.

It'll look like this.

[image: Drone jammer]

Comment: You can also just turn it off, it has a switch on one side.  You see it in the image to the right of the PC, in light blue-ish.

Comment: generators and SAM sites can be one-shotted with a sniper rifle if you hit the generator switch or "bump-out" (that looks similar to a switch) on the SAM. I have not found a spot on a jammer yet.

Comment: I turned off and destroyed the Jammer, still jammed. I also destroyed the generator, still jammed.

Comment: @Josh Some larger bases, usually Unidad, have more than one jammer.